# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController crashes in IOS 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have problem with ABPeoplePickerNavigationController in IOS 7 with the following error

```
*** -[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x9b4b050
```

on IOS 6 it is working fine but in ios 7 it gives this error with zombies enabled without zombies it was like

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0x0)
```

than i enable zombies
here is my code

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {  
       [super viewDidLoad];
       self.contacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
       self.addressBook=ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
      [self checkAddressBookAccess];
 }     
 (void)requestAddressBookAccess
 {  
        ContactsViewController * __weak weakSelf = self;

        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(self.addressBook, ^(bool granted,                             CFErrorRef error)
                                         {
                                             if (granted)
                                             {
                                                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                     [weakSelf accessGrantedForAddressBook];

                                                 });
                                             }
                                         });
 }
    -(void)accessGrantedForAddressBook
    {      
       NSMutableArray *savedContacts=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[DatabaseHandler getAllContacts]];
        if (savedContacts &&savedContacts.count!=0) 

       [self.contacts addObjectsFromArray:savedContacts];
    }
   - (IBAction)popUpAddExistingContact:(id)sender {    

    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [picker setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

 }
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{


NSString *viewControllerDesc=[viewController description];
NSString *t_st = @"ABContactViewController";
NSRange rang =[viewControllerDesc rangeOfString:t_st options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if (rang.length == [t_st length])
{
    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(addPerson:)];
}
else if([navigationController isKindOfClass:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class]] && [viewController isKindOfClass:[ABPersonViewController class]])
{
    ABPersonViewController *DVC=(ABPersonViewController*)viewController;
    self.currentPerson=DVC.displayedPerson;
    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(addPerson:)];

}
else{
    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}

navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel:)];
}
-(IBAction)addPerson:(id)sender{

if (self.currentPerson!=NULL)
{
    CFStringRef firstName;
    int recordID;
    firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(self.currentPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    recordID = ABRecordGetRecordID(self.currentPerson);
    MyContact *contact=[[MyContact alloc] init];
    contact.Name=(__bridge NSString *)(firstName);
    contact.contactID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",recordID];

    contact.phones=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(self.currentPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++)
    {
        CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j);
        CFStringRef locLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, j);
        NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *)phoneNumberRef;

        [contact.phones addObject:phoneNumber];

        CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
        CFRelease(locLabel);
    }


    CFRelease(firstName);
    //CFRelease(lastName);
}
//[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void ){

    [self.popUpContactView removeFromSuperview];

}];
```

}
as soon as peoplepickercontroller is dismissed app crashed in ios 7

```
*** -[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xb236c00
0x17d811:  jmp    0x17d90c                  ; ___forwarding___ + 1020
Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_1386_BPT,sucode 0x0)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to set peopleViewController delegates to nil before dismissing and disable second possible call of this action during some time (like if user pressed button several times). Assume you have a reference to ABPeoplePickerNavigationController instance. Something name like self.adressBook;

Then before dismissing PeoplePickerNavigationController set

```
self.adressBook.peoplePickerDelegate = nil
self.adressBook.delegate = nil;
```

and make sure **that you do not call** your peoplePickerNavigationController reference **after** dismissing or your reference to this instance is of **weak**, not **assign** type.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)popUpAddExistingContact:(id)sender {    

ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
[picker setDelegate:self];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I think it is because the view controller created is not retained,
Call [self addChildViewController:picker] or else maintain a "strong" reference for it

Comment: i have already tried that by making ABPeoplePickerNavigationController as property of my class but it not worked for me....

Comment: I am also calling method for posting the contact on server before CFRelease on firstName ,with that i am adding my special label and phone number in the native contact